# Open jQuery Dialog from Custom Button

Tags: javascript, custom-button, jquery

We have a custom button on the detail page of the case designed to open a modal dialog popup, however receiving the $g(...).dialog is not a function error message. I've searched around the web and can't find a solution that quite fits, below is code, any suggestions are much appreciated:

```
    {!REQUIRESCRIPT('//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js')}
{!REQUIRESCRIPT('//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js')}
try {

var html = '<div id="dialog" title="Drivers License Builder"><p> Here is the first line of the DL builder</p></div>';

   var $g = jQuery.noConflict();
    $g(function() {
        $g('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css"/>');

        $g("#dialog").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Generate License": function() {
                    $g(this).dialog("close");
                },
                "Cancel": function() {
                    $g(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
    });
}

catch(error) {
    alert(error);
}
```

Comment: Is there a specific error you are trying to catch?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check the following things: 1. Button Behavior  Execute JavaScript
2. JavaScript:

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT('//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js')} 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT('//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js')} 

var html = '<div id="dialog" style="display: none" title="Drivers License Builder"><p> Here is the first line of the DL builder</p></div>'; 

var $g = jQuery.noConflict(); 
$g(function() { 
    $g('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css"/>'); 
    $g('body').append(html); 

    $g("#dialog").dialog({ 
        autoOpen: true, 
        modal: true, 
        buttons: { 
            "Generate License": function() { 
                $g(this).dialog("close"); 
            }, 
            "Cancel": function() { 
                $g(this).dialog("close"); 
            } 
        } 
    }); 
});
```

The thing is that you were not appending the dialog in your html and directly displaying it. So first add it to html. Then display it.

Also set the dialog `autoOpen` attribute to `true` so that it shows up automatically.
P.S. The above code works in my D.E. org.
[image: Screenshot]

**P.S.**  Select this as an accepted answer if it works for you

Comment: Saket thanks for the suggestion, I've updated the code to your specs and its still not working. I am still receiving (based on browser) undefined is not a function.

Comment: I tried it in my dev org however and it is working, so I am thinking now that there is something blocking it our sandbox where I am testing