# Confirm Dialog Box On Detail Page

Tags: javascript, onclick, detail-page

I wanna add a custom button (Send Mail) on contact detail page, And is email field is having an email then on click he ask with a popup "Wanna send a mail ?" And wanna add 'Yes' Or 'No' instead off 'Ok' and 'Cancel' .

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no exact and simple solution for this OK and CANCEL in Confirm Popup using javascript. But you can do this with the help of JQUERY. Try the below link to understand better...

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/823790/javascript-confirm-popup-yes-no-button-instead-of-ok-and-cancel

Update:

[Open jQuery Dialog from Custom Button](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/63291/open-jquery-dialog-from-custom-button)

https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000h9p6AAA

Hope this helps...

Comment: ,OK! But can we use jQuery onclick of button that is add to detail page of any contact's record.,????

Comment: I think you can...Just see my updated Links for that....

Comment: Thnks a lot Subhash :)

Answer (score 0):

onclick="return confirm('Wanna send a mail?');"

If you return a false onclick the method will not be called.
The confirm function returns true or false (OK or Cancel).

/////////----------------------------------------///////

Display Type : Detail Page Button

Behavior : Execute Javascript

Content Source : Onclick Javascript

and in the text box copy the below JS code ,

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/20.0/connection.js")} 
    {!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/20.0/apex.js")} 
    var x;
    if (confirm("Wanna send a mail!") == true) {
        x = "YES";
    } else {
        x = "NO";
    }
    if(x == 'NO'){ 
      window.location.replace('/{!Account.Id}')
    } 

else { 
window.location.replace('/apex/AccountDetail?id={!Account.Id}') //replace your VF page here
}
```

Comment: It'll show OK and Cancel But i want instead of them Yes and No